# How do I use a domain account to connect to a database using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, dns, custom-action, vs-web-site-project

I want to create a database using the custom action in the website setup project. but i'm facing a problem doing that in the "website setup project", but when using the regular "setup project", every thing went fine without a problem...

the problem was from the authentication when I want to access the database. It seems that when I use the "setup project" it use my actual username,pass, & the domain. while in the "website setup project" it uses my computer name & for that reason it will not work. since, it doesn't have access to the database.

So, I need a way to tell the website to use my account (I will pass it through the custom action) that include my username,pass, & the domain.

How I can do that in the C#? is there is an API to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass Windows credentials in a connection string. How you would do this is to run your website in IIS(7 and above) and configure your app pool Identity to run under the account you want. See how here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(WS.10).aspx

This is not how it is done normally though. Normally you would create a sql account in your sql server and then in your connection string you would do something like this:

"Data Source=[ServerName]; Initial Catalog=[DatabaseName]; User Id=[SqlAccount]; Password=[SqlAccountPassword]"

You can then go once step further in sql and configure what access to give to the website account etc.

Comment: I would dispute that you normally create an account in SQL. The normal approach would be to use a Windows account and impersonate that account to connect using SSPI - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx

Comment: @Steve, in my experience impersonation isn't the norm. This is due to the fact that it breaks connection pooling and only work in an intranet scenario.

Comment: @Steve the first step was using impersonation, but honestly I can't see any reason why not to rather use a sql account, it just gives you that much more flexibility?

Comment: According to MSDN "When possible, use Windows Authentication." see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905171(SQL.80).aspx. There is a lot to this topic, suggest you search for other questions on SO that discuss it - there are a few :-)

Comment: @BenCr - it doesn't break connection pooling - again already covered on SO, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692500/windows-integrated-authentication-conflict-with-ms-sql-2000-db-connection-with-in

Comment: @BenCr - he's talking about impersonating the authenticated user, that will indeed break pooling, I would suggest ASP.Net should use trusted subsystem approach and this implies impersonating a single know role or user. You do not need to use SQL auth to get connection pooling.

Comment: My appologies. I didn't understand what you meant by SSPI and latched onto impersonate. To be fair the question is confusing at best and it doesn't mention a specific DB engine so windows authentication might not be available. I still suspect that usually IIS would be set to run as a domain account that has been granted access to connect to the DB rather than use any sort of impersonation. To recommend windows authentication at all you've got to assume a lot about the environment and those details are just not present in this question.

Comment: I agree, there are a lot of unaccounted variables that we would have to take into consideration, Interesting discussion though!